# Streamlit app not working stuck on please wait

Tags: python, streamlit

i am trying to run a streamlit app but once i try to run the app it stuck on the please wait...

python version = 3.10.4
streamlit version = 1.12.0

Code

```
import streamlit as st

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

st.title('Uber pickups in NYC')
```

json file configuration:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name":"Python:Streamlit",
            "type":"python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "streamlit",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "${file}",
                "--server.port",
                "5677"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

what am i doing wrong and how to make it work.

Comment: It might be the version. You can try upgrading the version with `pip install --upgrade streamlit`

Comment: i did upgrade to the latest version 1.12.1

Comment: How did you run it? Make sure you are running the right file, because if the file do not exist it will get stucked like that.

Comment: no i am running the right file  because after 10 min it runs normally

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try to use the 1.11.0 version of Streamlit with

```
pip install --upgrade streamlit==1.11.0
```

Comment: Looks like this version is too old, getting dependency errors with other modules, is there a fix now?